# How to manage multiple refs between parent and children in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm able to manage 1 ref between parent and 1st child, but whenever I tried to do same I'm not able to do that,

In my case I've main parent class and 9 children class, I need to fetch data from all the 9 classes into parent one.

Here's my parent class : where I'm passing reference to child classes

```
<View style={styles.bodyContainer}>
   {pageIndex === 1 && <Step1 ref={this.child} />}
   {pageIndex === 2 && <Step2 ref={this.child} />}
   {pageIndex === 3 && <Step3 ref={this.child} />}
   {pageIndex === 4 && <Step4 ref={this.child} />}
   {pageIndex === 5 && <Step5 ref={this.child} />}
   {pageIndex === 6 && <Step6 ref={this.child} />}
   {pageIndex === 7 && <Step7 ref={this.child} />}
   {pageIndex === 8 && <Step8 ref={this.child} />}
   {pageIndex === 9 && <Step9 ref={this.child} />}
</View>
```

I've created reference like below:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.child = React.createRef();
  }
```

Like below I managed to pass data from child class to parent one :

```
  saveStep1Data = () => {
    const {
      EDFLAG_NeckPainTenderness,
      REDFLAG_DoubleVision,
      REDFLAG_TinglingBurning,
      REDFLAG_Headache,
      REDFLAG_SeizureConvulsion,
      REDFLAG_LossConsciousness,
      REDFLAG_DeterioratingConciousState,
      REDFLAG_Vomiting,
      REDFLAG_RestlessAgitationCombative,
    } = this.state;

    const obj = [
      EDFLAG_NeckPainTenderness,
      REDFLAG_DoubleVision,
      REDFLAG_TinglingBurning,
      REDFLAG_Headache,
      REDFLAG_SeizureConvulsion,
      REDFLAG_LossConsciousness,
      REDFLAG_DeterioratingConciousState,
      REDFLAG_Vomiting,
      REDFLAG_RestlessAgitationCombative,
    ];

    return obj;
  };
```

I'm triggering the action to fetch child class data like below :

```
        <Text
          style={styles.saveText}
          onPress={() => {
            const step1Data = this.child.current.saveStep1Data();
            console.log(step1Data);
          }}>
          save
        </Text>
```

All the things with only 1 child class is working great for me, but I'm not getting desired result with multiple references with multiple children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In above case, I found a major issue with the data rendering,
I'm rendering all my components (Step1 to Step9) in root method conditionally,
App is initialising only Step1's reference because of we have manage all components conditionally the app will render only 1 Component according to conditions.

Solution: We must have to write all Component's code in 1 root file for doing stuff like I described in my question

Answer (score 0):

you need to create multiple ref for each child and pass it to child as a props

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.child1 = React.createRef();
    this.child2 = React.createRef();
    this.child3 = React.createRef();
    this.child4 = React.createRef();
      ... // so on
 
  }
```

And you need to pass different reference to the child as props

```
<View style={styles.bodyContainer}>
   {pageIndex === 1 && <Step1 ref={this.child1} />}
   {pageIndex === 2 && <Step2 ref={this.child2} />}
   {pageIndex === 3 && <Step3 ref={this.child3} />}
   {pageIndex === 4 && <Step4 ref={this.child4} />}
   ...// So on
</View>
```

You also need to change the function

```
 <Text
    style={styles.saveText}
    onPress={() => {
        const step1Data = this.child1.current.saveStep1Data();
        const step2Data = this.child2.current.saveStep1Data();
        ...// so On
        console.log(step1Data);
        console.log(step2Data);
    }}>
        save
 </Text>
```

Comment: thanks @rashi, but when try to manage like you said, I'm not getting the desired result moreover this time I didn’t even get step1Data as well